# Postgresql Jsonb Field Sum

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to sum Unique ids in grouped result.

My data in database field:

```
user_ids:
{"user_id": [213, 199, 2]}
{"user_id": [213, 2]}
{"user_id": [212]}
{"user_id": [2, 213]}
{"user_id": [266, 199]}
```

My Query:

```
select 
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT(jsonb_array_length(user_login_conflicts.user_ids -> 'user_id') - 1)) as user_ids
from "user_login_conflicts"
left join "users" on user_login_conflicts.user_ids -> 'user_id' @> CAST(CONCAT('[', users.id, ']') as JSONB)
where user_login_conflicts.user_ids -> 'user_id' is not null
group by "users"."id"
```

Result is below

```
user_ids:
{1,2}
{1,2}
{0}
{1,2}
{1}
```

I dont want to json result. I want sum result. Like this.

```
user_ids:
3
3
0
3
1
```

How can I sum my jsonb array result?

Comment: [Edit] the question and include the `CREATE` statements for both tables and `INSERT` statements for the sample data for them.

Comment: So you want to `SUM` instead of `ARRAY_AGG`, is that all?

Comment: Yes @Bergi . If I can use sum, my problem will be solved. 

If I use this style:
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT SUM(jsonb_array_length(user_login_conflicts.user_ids -> 'user_id') -1)) 
I am getting this error: ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested.

If I use this:
SUM(DISTINCT CONCAT(jsonb_array_length(user_login_conflicts.user_ids -> 'user_id') -1))
Result: ERROR: function sum(text) does not exist

Comment: You should use the second one, and drop the `CONCAT` call that converts the integer to a string for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use unnest and a subquery, similar to this:

```
select (select sum(s) from unnest(col1) s) from 
    (VALUES (array[1,2]), 
            (array[1,2]),
            (array[0]),
            (array[1,2]),
            (array[1])
    ) as q(col1);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dtEv5BFAYJTvm45FtNjomL/0